# ODATA : Query attributes in OData WebService

Tags: odata

I am setting up a ODATA Web Service and wondering if there are limitations to the number of Query attributes to be passed to the OData Webservice.

What would be the performance  implications for 'N' number of query attributes to OData Web Service?

For Ex: 
In the Odata Web Service Url below there are five query attributes

https://mydomain.ca/gpscontent?Version=A&Province=ON&Insurer=All&Form=All&ContentType=List

mydomain.ca: domain name of the service 
Query Attributes: Version, Province, Insurer, Form, ContentType

Are there any performance implications of using N Query Attributes? What would be a good number without seeing performance implications?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no baseline performance define for odata as it varies based on situation and amount of data odata service serves.**So giving some generic guidelines:**

The main parameters affecting performance of odata API is no of call and the response sizes. There is one nice article on odata practices for performance, probably you can refer that: [reference](http://developer.webnodes.com/odata-performance-tips)

Looking at your query pattern you are filtering with each query option so each option should reduce the response size and also reduce the no of calls that you will make to odata service.